# Where is topic-paritition-broker and segment-topic info saved in Pulsar?

Tags: apache-pulsar

Read the documentation: https://pulsar.apache.org/docs/en/concepts-architecture-overview/
I am not able to figure out:

1. Where does Pulsar store that which broker is assigned to a topic partition?
2. How does pulsar know which segment is of which topic-partition? Whenever a new segment is finally closed and persisted in bookie, how does Pulsar save that the segment belongs to which topic?
3. How do brokers figure out that they have to query which bookie for data for a topic when a read request comes?

Are all these stored in zookeeper?

Answer (score 2):

Yes, all these metadata are stored in ZooKeeper.
Topic load balancing is done by a leader elected service and data stored in `/loadbalance/bundle-data`.
Topic to ledger/segment info are stored under the path `/managed-ledgers`